# Tutorials related to the transformation of building geometries from CityGML to KML/Collada?

Tags: kml, gml, collada

I have some 3D building geometries in CityGML that I want to transform into KML/KMZ. Apparently the way KML works is to build the geometry in Collada and do the georeferencing in the actual KML file.

I don't want to use a program to do the transformation but rather want to do it by hand to understand how KML/Collada works. Do you know good tutorials that focus on the manual creation of 3D geometries in Collada and the georeferencing in KML?